# Variable completion in Octave GUI Editor

Tags: octave, readline, tab-completion

I mean to get completion of variable names, function names, function argument names, and keywords in Octave, similarly as in Eclipse CDT, e.g.
This works in the Command window, but not in the Editor, where only keywords and functions can be completed.

[Official documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Commands-For-Completion.html) indicates `<Tab>` and `<M-?>` should work.
If I press `<Tab>` I get a Tab character inserted.
And I do not know which is the `M`odifier key. Plus, I have a Spanish keyboard, so the question mark is obtained with `<Shift>+'`, so I am not sure how will it work if I find the correct `M` key.

**How can I enable it for the Editor?**

Notes:

1. *Help* -> *About* shows

   > GNU Octave, version 4.4.1... configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32"...

   Using Octave portable under Win 10.
2. I found files `<octave-dir>\etc\inputrc.default` and `<octave-dir>\share\octave\4.4.1\m\startup\inputrc`
3. There is a file `C:\Users\user1\.config\octave\qt-settings` containing

   ```
   ...
   [editor]
   ...
   codeCompletion=true
   ...
   codeCompletion_threshold=2
   codeCompletion_keywords=true
   codeCompletion_octave_builtins=true
   codeCompletion_octave_functions=true
   codeCompletion_document=false
   codeCompletion_case=true
   codeCompletion_replace=false
   ...
   tab_indents_line=false
   ```
4. [This](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Readline-patch-for-high-CPU-usage-td4659649.html) refers to the speed of `readline` for Octave under Win. I have speed issues with `readline` of my Portable Msys2 under Win 10, but this is a different issue.

Comment: Btw, Octave 5.x is stable now. Are you trying to to this in the command window or the editor?

Comment: @Andy - Good point. In the Editor. In the command window it works fine.
I edited the OP.

Comment: @Andy - Would you say it is ok not to have tab completion in the editor?

Comment: I do not use the GUI but I think it's possible that tab completition in the editor was never implemented because no one thought on it. You can ask on the help-mailinglist where the chances are good to find some developers working on the GUI

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the editor widget, select `Edit > Preferences`.
Select the `Editor` tab.
Look for `Auto Completion`.
Select `Match words in document`.

Comment: This is mildly helpful, but far from tab completion as in other languages/editors, which understand the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially no references that mention completion specifically in the editor.
The [only one I found](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/function-name-autocompletion-parameter-hint-or-Intelli-sense-feature-in-GUI-Octave-editor-td4663659.html), from 2014, stating that:

> There is no editor completion on all known function names, nor on 
>   parameter lists of known functions. There is an open bug report 
>   requesting function name completion in the editor, see 
>   http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41371.
>
> The GUI is an experimental new feature in the 3.8 release, please 
>   consider helping to improve it for 4.0 by joining the maintainers 
>   mailing list or participating on the bug tracker (even submitting 
>   feature request bugs if you want).

So at that time it was not available.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - In that bug, only function name completion is referred to, and it is actually working. But no variable completion (either local or function arguments).